# Recommended hardware to learn tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm a software developer and I want to experiment with AI, machine learning etc. I want to learn about the different algorithms and techniques that are readily available, how to use them and what algos are appropriate for different types of challenges. TensorFlow looks like good software to start experimenting with, so I will start with TF.

I'm not interested in image processing. I'm mostly interested in making sense of patterns in data and making predictions.

Will I be able to experiment with all of the common examples and try out all the algorithms and features of TF with just a modern i7 with 8 threads or will I definitely need a GPU in order to not wait hours between each experiment?

If I do need a GPU, would an entry-level CUDA 3.0+ GPU suffice (example Geforce 730M with 2GB RAM, probably the cheapest compatible GPU)
Or would I need something with more punch and RAM like the 1050Ti/1080GTX/Ti etc?

Is it practical to learn on google or AWS or am I better off buying the hardware?

My fear is that I drop a lot of cash on a fancy graphics card and then don't really get into ML programming, and then it's a waste of money.
I have no idea if I'll even find it interesting/useful. So I'm not trying to conquer the world with ML just yet.

To sum up, my short term goals:

1. Get some experience with ML so that I know what techniques/algos are available/good for diff types of tasks.
2. See if I find ML interesting
3. Learn what kind of hardware I need if I want to invest further.

I can afford to buy a 1080Ti to experiment with, but I don't want to waste money without knowing more. If I buy a cheaper GPU like 1050Ti can I add a 1080Ti later or is it best if all my GPU's are the same?

Comment: You will get most of the answers from : http://timdettmers.com/2015/03/09/deep-learning-hardware-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Simply googling will give you most of your answers. But in short, yes you can use your CPU with TensorFlow.

You will need at least CUDA 7.5 and a compute capability of at least 3.0 on your GPU (http://www.nvidia.com/object/gpu-accelerated-applications-tensorflow-installation.html)

If you have no experience with machine learning yet I would suggest playing around with Scikit learn first (http://scikit-learn.org/). It's very easy to learn and playing around with something other than neural networks will give you a better understanding in the fundamentals of machine learning. Scikit learn does not require a GPU (GPU support is actually not provided).